# How to simulate touch events on Android device?

Tags: android, api, simulation, gesture, multi-touch

Does the Android API expose facilities for generating touch events, for example, repeatedly simulating different gestures on the screen for testing?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn adb commands will work for u or u need some kind of monkay testing tool commands ???

For adb commands u can use below shell commands...

adb shell input tap x y and also

adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 0 5 
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 1 29 
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 330 1 
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 0 0 
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 330 0 
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 0 0

Comment: Did u find best solution. If u found one please update it here or accept some answer so that others will know answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an Android Instrumention Test to implement UI auto testing in android, see [Tesing UI for a Single Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html#setup) and [Android Testing Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html).

If you are new to Android Test, I suggest you read [Activity Testing](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_testing.html) first.

Comment: Does it work for any application, even outside of the current application? Is there any sample of how to use it?