# Click SeekBar dotted handle with Accessibility Services

Tags: android, accessibility, accessibilityservice

I'm setting progress to a SeekBar programmatically using

```
    val arguments = Bundle()
    arguments.putFloat(
        AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_PROGRESS_VALUE,
        seekPosition
    )
    seekBarNode?.performAction(
        AccessibilityNodeInfo.AccessibilityAction.ACTION_SET_PROGRESS.id,
        arguments
    )
```

Seek happens but the content does not change. However, clicking on the dotted handle manually starts playing at that sought position.

Now, I'd like to click on the SeekBar at the dotted handle (check the image)

Is there a way to get the coordinates for that? I have the SeekBar node with the Rect details but they do not correspond to the dotted handle to perform a click at that position. (I've enabled pointer location updates from Dev options)

[image]

Comment: The seekbar only reflects some state. The video provides new values for the seekbar. The  accessiblity action provides new values to the seekbar. Nowhere does it say that that changing seekbar's value changes the video position. The relationship is inverse: video is *model*, seekbar is *view*. View observes model. If you know the progress value you can calculate the new position in video, set  the new position in video, and seekbar will observe the new position and update itself (I assume you already have that implemented).

Comment: @EugenPechanec the relationship you mentioned is correct. However, I'm controlling a 3rd party app here and the only mutable objects I see to change the video is the SeekBar. What are your thoughts on that

Comment: Hmm, can you get the dimensions of the seekbar and its max value? From that you could compute exact location where to issue a click event.

Comment: I have the Rect values of the SeekBar and the max/current value of the range. But how do I issue a click event to the dotted handle?
SeekBar coordinates
mBoundsInParent = {Rect@12092} "Rect(0, 0 - 1958, 148)"
mBoundsInScreen = {Rect@12093} "Rect(53, 768 - 2011, 916)"

Range Values - 
mCurrent = 1078692.0
mMin = 0.0
mMax = 1.0189E7

I don't see any pattern which would lead me to click the dotted handle which is the current position

Comment: Does `AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD` work for you? Check if that is working

Comment: @TarunLalwani it scrolls, but again I need to click the handle to resume it from that scrolled position

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775698/how-can-i-reliably-simulate-touch-events-on-android-without-root-like-automate, how about you simulate a touch ? `(screenX + (val-min) * width/ (max -min), screenY + height/2)`

Comment: how does that correspond to the seek bar handle coordinates?

Comment: @VeereshCharantimath, `screenX`, `screenY` is from `mBoundsInScreen` for the seekbar